# How to filter 2 indexed event fields, both fields array?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I have this event:

```
event onSubmissionBoth(bytes32[] indexed docHash, string[] indexed doc4DHash);
```

Now I log into the event like this:

```
function submitHash(bytes32[] calldata docHash,string[] calldata doc4DHash) external onlyOwner() {
       emit onSubmissionBoth(docHash,doc4DHash);
    }
```

But when I try to search it through web3.js I am a bit confused:

- Can I search for docHash only? i.e only with one field.
- Also trying this I get null:

  contract.events.onSubmissionBoth({
  filters: {docHash:["hashValue"],
  doc4DHash:web3.utils.sha3(["stringValue"])}},(s,events)=>{
  console.log(events)
  })

Is there a way to filter the two array fields? Because I only get null everytime I do it in this way.